# HTTP GET Request and Response

Tags: javascript, http, get, response

I'm trying to request some data from a webpage I have, through a HTTP GET request.

I only want the response to return certain data. Lets say I pass "apple" as a URL parameter, then I want the answer to exclude "apple".

I wrote a short script to accomplish this, but it doesn't run before the response is sent.

So instead of getting "banana" and "pear" in my response I get all of them including the script.

Please help

Webpage:

```
banana
apple
pear

<script>
const urlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('fruit');

document.querySelector("body").innerText = document.querySelector("body").innerText.replace(urlParam, "");
</script>
```

Desired response

```
banana
pear
```

Current response:

```
banana
apple
pear

<script>
const urlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('fruit');

document.querySelector("body").innerText = document.querySelector("body").innerText.replace(urlParam, "");
</script>
```

Comment: `I tried ...` show what you tried

Comment: "I wrote a short script to accomplish this, but it doesn't run before the response is sent." — Well no. That's a fundamental limitation of client-side JavaScript. It is included in the response and runs on the client.

Comment: Okay. Is there another solution then? All I want is to get "banana" and "pear" in my response.